# SwiftyJson nested array with model

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

How do I create a data model with SwiftyJSON and a 2nd set of nested array of objects? I'm able to parse and store the top level objects fine, but not the inner ones. noteimages in particular, I can't seem to figure out. Below is the api results and under that is how I am trying to do it, although not quite right.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "some title",
    "details": "here are some details",
    "userId": 1,
    "hidden": false,
    "createdAt": "2018-02-14T07:02:33.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-02-14T07:02:33.000Z",
    "contactId": 1,
    "noteimages": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "imageUrl": "someimage222.jpg",
            "userId": 1,
            "hidden": false,
            "createdAt": "2018-02-14T07:02:58.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-02-15T04:41:05.000Z",
            "noteId": 1
        }
    ]
}
]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in

        if response.result.error == nil {
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            do {
                if let json = try JSON(data: data).array {
                    print(json)
                    for item in json {
                        let title = item["title"].stringValue
                        let details = item["details"].stringValue

                        var noteImages: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
                        for image in item["noteimages"].arrayValue {
                            noteImages.append(image["imageUrl"])
                        }

                        let note = Note(title: title, details: details, noteImage: noteImages)
                        self.notes.append(note)
                    }
                    //print(response)
                    completion(true)
                }
            } catch {
                debugPrint(error)
            }

        } else {
            completion(false)
            debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are getting the value string in key `imageUrl` and you are adding as dictionary so if you need an array of dictionary you need to add those values in `item["noteimages"].arrayValue` directly or if you need an array of `imageUrl` you need to change the type of `noteImages` var to `String` type

```
var noteImages: [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]// this should be [String:AnyObject]] swifty way
for image in item["noteimages"].arrayValue {
    noteImages.append(image["imageUrl"]) //this is an String not an Dictionary
}
```

To fix this you need one of three options

**Option 1: Use an array of dictionary**

```
var noteImages: [[String:AnyObject]] = []
for image in item["noteimages"].arrayValue {
   if let imageDict = image as? [String:AnyObject]{
       noteImages.append(imageDict) //adding in a dictionary array
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Use an array of String**

```
var noteImages: [String] = []
for image in item["noteimages"].arrayValue {
   if let imageDict = image as? [String:AnyObject]{
       noteImages.append(imageDict["imageUrl"])
    }
}
```

**Option 3: convert your dictionary to a Model object**

```
var noteImages: [YourModelName] = []
for image in item["noteimages"].arrayValue {
   if let imageDict = image as? [String:AnyObject]{
       noteImages.append(YourModelName(dictionary:imageDict)) //adding in a model object created from a dictionary
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I just printed that data and it was a string. Trying to build the models with the wrong types.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
var notes = [Note]()
var noteImages = [NoteImage]()
```

....

```
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in

        if response.result.error == nil {
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            do {
                if let json = try JSON(data: data).array {
                    print(json)
                    for item in json {
                        let title = item["title"].stringValue
                        let details = item["details"].stringValue

                        //loop through nested array
                        for innerItem in item["noteimages"].arrayValue {
                            let noteImage = NoteImage(imageUrl: innerItem["imageUrl"].stringValue)
                            self.noteImages.append(noteImage)
                        }

                        print("note images: \(self.noteImages)")

                        let note = Note(title: title, details: details, noteImage: self.noteImages)
                        self.notes.append(note)
                    }
                    //print(response)
                    completion(true)
                }
            } catch {
                debugPrint(error)
            }

        } else {
            completion(false)
            debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
        }

    }
```